# Write html to custom header tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf

I'm struggling to understand how the header function is working in tcpdf.

Is is possible to use $pdf->writeHTML to the header?

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps

I would like to display 3 columns in the header.

```
 Column1 Column2 Column3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem solved, credits to Simon @ https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/505a9e13/

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
public function Header() {
    $headerData = $this->getHeaderData();
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
    $this->writeHTML($headerData['string']);
}
}
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setHeaderData($ln='', $lw=0, $ht='', $hs='<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1"><tr><td rowspan="3">test</td><td>test</td></tr></table>', $tc=array(0,0,0), $lc=array(0,0,0));
```

Comment: Do you know how to make `Header()` customisable with parameters?

Comment: I've found that if you want to customize, just create a function that uses `writeHTMLCell()` and calling it directly after `addPage()`.  I have yet to find a way to write dynamic headers with TCPDF.  Writing the HTMLCell allows me to just pop the same sized HTML in all necessary pages.  If you have dynamic content that will break pages then this won't work :(

I have yet to try footers.  I don't see it being so simple.

Comment: I tried t his solution just blank. Nothing shows on header section.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in. always show this error.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in. always show this error.

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved, this method is less complex and is more direct in insert HTML code in header

```
class MYTCPDF extends TCPDF {

  public function Header(){
     $html = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0"><tr><td rowspan="3">test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></table>';
     $this->writeHTMLCell($w = 0, $h = 0, $x = '', $y = '', $html, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $fill = 0, $reseth = true, $align = 'top', $autopadding = true);
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this way works as well:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF{
    public function Header(){
        $html = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0"><tr><td rowspan="3">test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></table>';
        $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
    }
}


$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->Output('pdfHeader.pdf', 'I');
```